# Is 301 redirects enough for RSS feeds, or will some readers fail?

Tags: website, 301-redirect, seo

I am in the process of moving an entire site from ID based pages to user friendly / descriptive urls, and I would like to move the blogs as well.

My problem is then, that I am uncertain if 301 redirects will be enough to be completely covered, as I am not sure if all readers support these, and I do not want to loose any subscribers if I can help it.

For regular HTML pages there is the [canonical "redirect"](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&hlrm=da&answer=139394), telling google and others, that the url is moved, but the old url is still valid, but I can not find a similar functionality for blogs. Does such a feature exist, or is 301 really going to work for all my subscribers? Alternatively, is duplicate content an issue for RSS feeds (not comparing to the site, but having multiple RSS feed links that really is the same content)?

Answer (score 2):

RSS is served over HTTP so the clients should be following the rules for an HTTP user agent as put forth in the rfq.  Any RSS reader should behave like a browser and serving RSS pages should be no different than other Web pages.  That said, though, there is no way to guarantee that all clients will be coded to the spec.  Do what you can according to the rules of HTTP.  Nobody can know with 100% certainty if all subscribers are going to follow the rules.

Comment: The ***real*** problem here I think is not "not following 301", but whether or not the subsribing system actually updates the URL and next time goes to the new one...